# Trouble executing server-side cgi code from javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, cgi

I am trying to send a message from the webclient via JavaScript or JQuery to the Apache2 webserver on Debian Jessie, to execute a compiled C program that sends a POSIX message_queue, but I cannot get it to work.

I have the following files in my cgi directory:
root@asus:/var/www/cgi-bin# ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 59008 Mar 20 17:47 mq_client.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   115 Mar 17 18:14 test.pl

mq_client.cgi is a C-compiled executable that generates the POSIX message. If I execute 
lachlan@asus:~$ /var/www/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi
the correct message is sent and received by the server.

Test.pl is a perl scrpt that generates html code and if I execute 
lachlan@asus:~$ /var/www/cgi-bin/test.pl
this works fine also and gives the output:
Content-type: text/html
Just testing.

If I use the chromium webserver as follows:
http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.pl
I get the correct result: 'Just Testing'

However, I have not been able to get the mq_client.cgi code to execute from the webserver. I have searched many website and tried many options as indicated below.

This is my code of “index.html” (Note the errors only occur when I press the button)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq_182.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function mapToggle(){
        // different options as indicated below
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "label"> </div>
        <form action = "" class = "mapButton">
            <p> <button type= "button" onclick = "mapToggle()" class = "button2property"> Map Toggle </button> </p>         
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The different options I have tried (one by one) in the location indicated above are:

// option 1.

```
var site = 22;          
$.ajax({type: "PUT", url: "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi", async: false,  data: site});
```

This gives the following 2 errors in Chromium:
    Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
jq_182.js:2 
    PUT http://localhost/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi 500 (Internal Server Error)

// option 2.

```
var site = 22;          
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi", async: false,  data: site});
```

This gives the following 2 errors:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
jq_182.js:2 
GET http://localhost/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi 500 (Internal Server Error)

// option 3.

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi");
myRequest.send();
```

This gives the following error code:
index2.html:21 GET http://localhost/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi 500 (Internal Server Error)

//option 4.

```
src = "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi";
```

No errors are indicated in Chromium, but there is also no message sent

// option 5.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi";
```

Resulting error: GET http://localhost/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi 500 (Internal Server Error)

// option 6. Also changed the filename to index.shtml

```
<!--#exec cmd="/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi" -->
```

No errors are indicated in Chromium, but there are no messages sent

// Option 7.

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("post", "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi", true);
```

No errors are indicated in Chromium, but there are no messages sent.

// Option 8.

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formx  = new FormData();
formx.append("dummy","data");
client.open("post", "/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi", true);    
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
client.send(formx);
```

Error: index2.html:45 POST http://localhost/cgi-bin/mq_client.cgi 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have reviewed many references and tried their suggestions, but have not yet solved the problem.

Any ideas on where to look for the problem would be appreciated.
Lachlan

The Server side code generates a POSIX Message queue:
The server code sends out a POSIX message to a server. The code is as follows:

```
int main(void) {
    char msg[5];

    // Open queue already created
    mqd_t mQueue = mq_open("q1", O_WRONLY, NULL);
    if (mQueue == (mqd_t) -1){
        puts("Queue Open Failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    puts("Queue Opened\n");

    // Send Message
    msg[0] = 22;
    if ( mq_send(mQueue, msg, 5, 1) == -1){
            puts("Queue Send Failure\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
    puts("Message Sent\n");
    mq_close(mQueue);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the Server code to receive the message queue:

```
int main(void) {
    char msg[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
    unsigned int prio;
    ssize_t msgLength = 0;

    // Create queue
    struct mq_attr attr;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 4;
    attr.mq_msgsize = 5;            
    mQueue = mq_open(“q1”, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, &attr);
    if (mQueue == (mqd_t) -1){
        puts("Queue Create Failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    puts("Queue Created\n");

    // get message - This blocks
    msgLength = mq_receive(mQueue, msg, MAX_MSG_SIZE, &prio);
    if (msgLength == -1){
        puts("Queue Read Failure\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    printf("Message Received: %i\n", (int)msg[0]);
    mq_close(mQueue);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The permissions to access the server queue are: 
S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO

The permissions for executing the cgi code are:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 59008 Mar 20 17:47 mq_client.cgi

If this is a permission problem can you suggest which permissions are missing?

Comment: All your examples either (a) Don't report the result or (b) Report the result as an Internal Server Error. You need to read the server logs (and possibly add more debugging to your server side code) to find the details of the server error. Making variations to the request without understanding why the server is throwing an error is a very poor approach to debugging.

Comment: The server code sends out a POSIX message to a server. The code is as follws:

int main(void) {
 mqd_t mQueue;
 char msg[5];

 // Open a message queue already created
 mQueue = mq_open(mQname, O_WRONLY, NULL);
 if (mQueue == (mqd_t) -1){
  puts("Message Queue Open Failed\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
 puts("Message Queue Opened\n");

 // Send Message
 msg[0] = 22;
 if ( mq_send(mQueue, msg, 5, 1) == -1){
   puts("Message Queue Send Failure\n");
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
 puts("Message Sent\n");

 puts("Message Queue Closed\n");
 mq_close(mQueue);
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: The server code sends out a POSIX message to a server. The code is as follows:

int main(void) {
 char msg[5];

 // Open queue already created
 mqd_t mQueue = mq_open("q1", O_WRONLY, NULL);
 if (mQueue == (mqd_t) -1){
  puts("Queue Open Failed\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
 puts("Queue Opened\n");

 // Send Message
 msg[0] = 22;
 if ( mq_send(mQueue, msg, 5, 1) == -1){
   puts("Queue Send Failure\n");
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
 puts("Message Sent\n");
 mq_close(mQueue);
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: I have added the server side code. What sort of result are you referring to in point a). What server logs are you referring to that I should review? How would i go forward to try and determine the source of the error. I have checked with teh test.pl code that the cgi code can be executed from the browser, and I have check that local execution of mq_client.cgi that the code works and generates the require message. What would be the next step and which logs should Iook at? Thanks Lachlan

Comment: Thanks. Your comments were helpful. I managed to find the error log. These indicate that the message queue was not opened successfully if you refer to the above code. The question is why? I create the Server message queue as follows:  mQueue = mq_open(mQname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, &attr);      All the permissions are covered so what could be wrong in opening the message queue via the web interface when opening by executing the code locally has no error? (Note that the queue name is the same in both because the code executes locally ok) Thanks Lachlan

Comment: "All the permissions are covered" — Are they? I have only an inkling of an idea as to what that code does, but does the user the script is being run as by the HTTP server really have permission?

Comment: "executing the code locally" — presumably from a standard user account and not the HTTP system user

Comment: The permissions for receiving the message on the queue are shown in the code above which are:     S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO    and the permissions to execute the cgi code are:         -rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 59008 Mar 20 17:47 mq_client.cgi. Can you suggest what permissions may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found another post that helped solve the problem. Yes it was a permissions problem. The program permissions were overriding the message queue permissions. Once this was addressed the problem was solved.
Regards
Lachlan